# How do I use JavaScript in my <select> options list?

Tags: html

How do I use

```
          <select>
          <option>numbers1-100</option>
          </select>
```

I have to use 1 to 100 numbers in my option list.Typing all the options takes time and makes code bigger.I guess we have to use javascript to make it work using for loop and document write.But I dont know how to put the code in the right way.How do i list the options list using java script? I mean the java script should be beside my label;example

```
        number : 1-1oo \\ here the options list should be printed
```

and number can be anywhere but the script should print options list beside  the number.How do i make it ? Unable to figure it out.Been trying from an hour or so.

Comment: How old are you? Old-time typewriter users used to type zeros with "o"s as you did which makes them typographically more correct inside paragraphs... :) Funny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this function in your `<script>` tags or include it within a script. Than call the function, `createSelectOption()` whenever you need the select box to be created.

Here is how you would have it loaded on page load with just javascript: `

```
function createSelectOption() {    
    var select_option = '<select>';
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { 
       select_option += '<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
    }
    select_option += '</select>';
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = select_option;
}
```

I have included a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/kvuqQ/1/) to show you that it should be working/

Comment: How do i call a javascript function without any condition?

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  But you need to modify it to include a `value`.  So something like `select_option += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';`

Comment: is it possible .. num : "javascriptfunction()" will that work?

Comment: My question is not just the code but how do i make it work ? how do use it guys?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really use javascript for this, it would usually be better using a server-side language such as php. You could use a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or a [while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) to do this quite easily

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryh7k/1/

```
var selectEle = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
    optionEle = undefined;

for (var i=1;i<=100;i++) {
    optionEle = document.createElement('option');
    optionEle.setAttribute('value', i.toString());
    optionEle.innerText = i.toString();
    selectEle.appendChild(optionEle);
}
```

Comment: [jsperf on parsing the `option` strings vs `createElement() method`](http://jsperf.com/createelement-vs-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case:

```
<select>
<script>
for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
}
</script>
</select>
```

But there are of course problems with this. First, people without JS will not see any options and having a SCRIPT tag inside a SELECT is not that nice either.

```
<select id="container"></select>
<script>
var s = document.getElementById('container');
var opts = '';
for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    opts += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
s.innerHTML = opts;
</script>
```

Comment: but how do i call that margus ? How do i execute the script right after the number .You people giving me the code but Im unable to understand how to call it

Comment: I have written the code i dont know where to put it and how to call it

Comment: Whereever you want that selectbox to appear, just paste the second example. And if you have multiple ones one the same HTML page, just change the ID in both the select tag and in the script.